# Как подключить гем bootstrap_tokenfield_rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Добавил в `gemfiles`

```
gem 'bootstrap_tokenfield_rails'
```

Добавил в application.js:

```
//= require bootstrap-tokenfield
```

Добавил application.scss

```
@import bootstrap-tokenfield
```

Используя form_for пробую использовать его в представлении, но поле как было обычным селектом, так и осталось.

```
<%= f.select :tag_ids, Tag.all.collect {|t| [t.name, t.id]}, {}, multiple: true, class: 'tokenize' %>
```

Comment: Потому что, [как гласит документация, которую надо внимательно читать](https://github.com/icicletech/bootstrap-tokenfield-rails#usage), поле надо ещё инициализировать из JS.

Comment: @D-side вот в этом и проблема. У меня sass. А на сайте css

Comment: У вас явные проблемы с внимательностью, я хоть слово о CSS сказал? :)

Comment: пардон) переработал сегодня.

Comment: @D-side Так как его проинициализировать?*

Comment: вот эту строку нужно вставить `$('input.tokenize').tokenfield();`

Comment: Ну, там есть пример на JS, он должен в вашем случае сработать.

Comment: а как быть с <input type="text" class="tokenize">? как его объявить с помощью form_for

Answer (score 0):

В `application.js` допишите вот это для инициализации плагина:

```
$(function () {
  $('input.tokenize').tokenfield();
});
```

Comment: а как быть с <input type="text" class="tokenize">? как его объявить с помощью form_for

Comment: @Radzhab я не оч могу понять как ты хочешь сделать( ты хочешь с твоего селекта выборку делать в этот инпут? или сделать инпут для ввода с возможностью выбора ?

Comment: @AndrewTymchenko у меня <select multiple="multiple" а нужно получить <input type="text"

Answer (score 0):

Я так понял тебе нужно с дефолтными значениями

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="tokenfield" value="что, то"/>
```

и сделай автокомплит

**file1.js.erb**

```
 $('#tokenfield').tokenfield({
      autocomplete: {
        source: [<%= Tag.all.collect {|t| t.name } %>],
        delay: 100
      },
      showAutocompleteOnFocus: true
    })
```